# Dataframe column is list of strings: how to apply transformation to each element?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Assuming a dataframe where a the content of a column is one list of 0 to n strings

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_w_list':[['c/100/a/111','c/100/a/584','c/100/a/324'],
                                 ['c/100/a/327'],
                                 ['c/100/a/324','c/100/a/327'],
                                 ['c/100/a/111','c/100/a/584','c/100/a/999'],
                                 ['c/100/a/584','c/100/a/327','c/100/a/999']
                                 ]})
```

How would I go about transforming the column (either the same or a new one) if all I wanted was the last set of digits, meaning

```
|  | target_still_list     |
|--|-----------------------|
|0 | ['111', '584', '324'] |
|1 | ['327']               |
|2 | ['324', '327']        |
|3 | ['111', '584', '999'] |
|4 | ['584', '327', '999'] |
```

I know how to handle this one list at a time

```
from os import path
ls = ['c/100/a/111','c/100/a/584','c/100/a/324']
new_ls = [path.split(x)[1] for x in ls]
# or, alternatively
new_ls = [x.split('/')[3] for x in ls]
```

But I have failed at doing the same over a dataframe. For instance

```
df['target_still_list'] = df['col_w_list'].apply([lambda x: x.split('/')[3] for x in df['col_w_list']])
```

Throws an `AttributeError` at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to apply transformation to each element?

For a data frame, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html).

For a series, you can use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) or [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply), which is your posted solution.

---

Your error is caused by the lambda expression. It takes an element `x`, so the type of `x` is `list`, you can directly iterate over its items.

The correct code should be,

```py
df['target_still_list'] = df['col_w_list'].apply(lambda x: [item.split('/')[-1] for item in x])
# or 
# df['target_still_list'] = df['col_w_list'].map(lambda x: [item.split('/')[-1] for item in x])
# or (NOTE: This assignment works only if df has only one column.)
# df['target_still_list'] = df.applymap(lambda x: [item.split('/')[-1] for item in x])
```

Comment: Your third option gives me an error, `Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1`.
But option 1 and 2 work like a charm. Thanks for that.
As a final question, do you know what the performance of this operation would be (in O notation)?

Comment: The third option works as soon as I change to either `df = df...` or
`df['col_w_list'] = df...`

Comment: 1. `pandas.DataFrame.applymap` returns `DataFrame` and the other two return `Series`. In your post, `df` has only one column, and in this case, the third option gives the same result as the others. 2. I don't know the exact time complexity, but all the three functions should be `O(N*T)`, where `N` is the number of elements to be handled, `T` is the time complexity of the transformation function.